# How to animate sliding on an image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I wrote this code for a image slider but i don't know how to make a sliding animation when swapping throw photos

So, if anyone can help I would be grateful.

html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Image Slider</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <img id="first" class="slide" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Fiat_127_2_v_sst.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slide" src="https://trustspringer.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/house-mouse-1.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slide" src="https://www.dw.com/image/40734768_303.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slide" src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" alt="">

    <button id="prev">prev</button>
    <button id="next">next</button>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

css :-

```
img{
width: 60%;
margin-left: 20%;
height: 50vh;
display: none;
}

#first{
display: block;
}
```

javascript :-

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
prev   = document.getElementById("prev"),
next   = document.getElementById("next"),
count  = 0;

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
images[count].style.display = "none";
if(count >= images.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
} else {
    count ++;
}
images[count].style.display = "block";
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
images[count].style.display = "none";
if(count <= 0) {
    count = images.length - 1;
} else {
    count --;
}
images[count].style.display = "block";
});
```

......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make an animation with the DOM.

The JavaScript should look like this:

```js
 var images = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
prev   = document.getElementById("prev"),
next   = document.getElementById("next"),
count  = 0;

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
images[count].style.display = "none";
if(count >= images.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
} else {
    for (var i; i <= 100; i++) //example numbers
    {
         images[count].style.textAlign = i;
    }
    count ++;
}
images[count].style.display = "block";
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
images[count].style.display = "none";
if(count <= 0) {
    count = images.length - 1;
} else {
    for (var i; i >= -100; i--) //example numbers
    {
         images[count].style.textAlign = i;
    }
    count --;
}
images[count].style.display = "block";
});
```